# Is there any way to edit columns with a form in Access?

Tags: ms-access

Seems not to be possible, since Access relates rows not columns, but I would like to have the option to edit columns by a form, for example I have the next table:

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OYjm.png)

I want to allow the user to edit and change the actual name of  A1, A2 and A3 by the use of a form like this:

[Imaginative Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xfcs8.png)

The form of the image it's just for ilustrate, not sure but maybe this can be accomplished by some VBA code.

Comment: Users should keep far away from tables, let alone from any kind of table objects modifications. Bad idea, why would you want to do this for starters?

Comment: Okey, sure that's pretty logic, user must not interfer with tables, I see that my problem resides in the correct definition of tables in order to just edit the rows as it must be.

Comment: Numbered columns usually point to missing normalisation.If you want the labes to be editable create a table with labelIDd and LabelName and assign them to the label controls on `Form_Load()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using the form wizard, create a column-based form. You can of course also create the form yourself. In the details section align the fields as desired:

[image: Columns in the details section]